# For loop on form not functing properly

Tags: django

I have a feature that allows users to upload multiple images to their blog but it is not working correctly. When a user uploads multiple images only one of them is uploaded to the postgres db.

view

```
def DetailPostView(request, pk):
model = Post
post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)

if request.method == 'POST':
    test = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    files = request.FILES.getlist('images')
    if test.is_valid():
        for f in files:
            instance = test.save(commit=False)
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
            instance.save()
    else:
        print(instance.errors)
         
postgallery = PostImages.objects.filter(post_id=post) 

context = {
    'post':post, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm, 'postgallery':postgallery
    }
return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', context)
```

form

```
class PostImagesForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = PostImages
    fields = ('images',)
    widgets = {
        'images': forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'multiple': True}),
    }
```

you can see i am getting the list of files via the `files = request.FILES.getlist('images')` then running a for loop on the contents.

If I break the code in the stack trace I can see that the two files are in the list so i am very confused on why it is not properly iterating though the list and uploading each file to the db.

[image]

**Update**

Took a look into the [docs and found a section on multi image upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/file-uploads/) and the docs are doing it the same way I am. Still very confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue was the because I was not passing the current image into the model so it only uploaded the first image.

Solution

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):
            test = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
            if test.is_valid():
                instance = test.save(commit=False)
                instance.post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
                instance.images = f
                instance.save()
```